# java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit subtracting dates

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

Ok, this is fairly simple but it seems to be doing something I don't understand.  What I'm trying to do is get a time-in, say 12:30pm, and a time-out, say 1pm, and calculate the hours between those.  For some reason it is giving me ten hours difference (setting time-in with punch in and time-out with punch out, which are both Date strings).  I wonder if I could be formatting the date wrong?  here is the code:

```
public void getDailyHours(){
    for (Employee e : employees){
        try {

            Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss a",          Locale.ENGLISH).parse(e.getPunchIn());
            Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(e.getPunchOut());
            long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
            long diffHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
            e.setDailyHours(diffHours);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmployeeArray.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        }


}
```

Comment: `DD` should be `dd` and `HH` should be `hh` because of `a` refer: [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and post the input String

Comment: OK, thanks.  I couldn't find the actual format of the defaultDate for the date class.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss a
```

to

```
MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a
```

assuming your String input is like

```
 Jan 21, 2014 10:12:12 AM
```

---

**See**

- [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)